# URLConnection receive wrong text from php server

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I have an app that has 4 activities.in first activity I want to request some text from my website (PHP file). For first time that I press button to get data it works fine but in next times that I press button, it returns a CORRECT text but concatenates it with previous text.see the example:

```
First press: returns: "abc"
Second press: returns: "abcabc" (must be return abc)
Third press: returns: "abcabcabc" (must be return abc)
.
```

1. I clear text view each time.
2. I close connection each time.
3. I close the `BufferedReader` each time.
4. I close.

ACTIVITY1:

```
try{
    URL u = new URL(uu);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
    pr.print("code=3&arg1=" + str);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
    String l;
    while ((l=br.readLine())!=null){
        z = z + "\n" + l;
    }
    br.close();
    pr.close();
    con.disconnect();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tx.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            tx.setText("");
            tx.setText(z);
        }
    });
}
catch (final Exception ex){
}
```

Comment: Add `z="";` before while loop

Comment: You may need to flush the `PrintStream` before getting the input. I would use `write()` rather than `print()` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you declared the `z` String, but you are obviously appending to it.

You should either clear it, or use a new String for each request.

And use a `StringBuilder`. You memory usage will be much lower.